# Passing dialog data to CKEditor widget template

Tags: ckeditor

I have created a CKEditor widget and an associated dialog with a few fields.

I would like to directly place the values of these fields into the generated template of the widget. I cannot seem to figure out how this work though.

Dialog field:

```
{
  id: 'message',
  type: 'textarea',
  label: 'Message',
  'default': '',
  setup: function( widget ) {
    this.setValue( widget.data.message );
  },
  commit: function( widget ) {
    widget.setData( 'message', this.getValue() );
  }
}
```

plugin template:

```
init: function( editor ) {
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'note', this.path + 'dialogs/note.js' );

    editor.widgets.add( 'note', {

      button: 'Create a note',

      dialog: 'note',

      template:
        '<div class="admonition note">' +
        '<p class="first admonition-title">Title</p>' +
        '<p class="last">Message</p>' +
        '</div>',
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by directly manipulating the DOM due to the fact that widget templates are immutable.

The Widget API can help us here with the usage of `parts`, `init`, `edit`, `data` and the methods `setData` and `setHtml`.

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('note',{
  ...
  requires: 'widget,dialog',
  init: function(editor) {
    const html =
      '<div class="note">' +
      '<p class="note-title">Note</p>' +
      '<p class="note-message">Message</p>' +
      '</div>';
    const path = this.path;
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('note',path + 'dialogs/note.js' );
    editor.widgets.add( 'note', {
      template: html,
      parts: {
        note: 'div.note',
        message: 'p.note-message'
      },
      upcast: function(element) {
        return element.name === 'div' && element.hasClass( 'note' );
      },
      init: function () {
        // called when loading the widget
        this.setData('message', this.parts.message.getHtml());
      },
      edit: function() {
        // called when opening the dialog
        const message = this.parts.message.getHtml();
        if (message !== this.data.message) {
          this.setData('message', message);
        }
      },
      data: function() {
        // called when you save the dialog
        this.parts.message.setHtml(this.data.message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```